# How can I use compressed DDS format textures with mip mapping?

Tags: c++, direct3d

Until now, I was setting my `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC::MipLevels` to 1, but in order to improve performance and quality of terrain textures, I've tried to swap it to textures with mipmaps. So this is the code I'm using to create a texture with mipmaps:

```
 D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC t2d;
ZeroMemory(&t2d, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));

UINT BindFlags = (D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | (m_Header.dwMipMapCount ? D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET : 0)); // if the texture has mipmaps then bind it to render target.

t2d.Format = GetDXGIFormat(m_Header.ddspf); // BC2_UNORM
t2d.Width = m_Header.dwWidth;
t2d.Height = m_Header.dwHeight;
t2d.MipLevels = !m_Header.dwMipMapCount ? 1 : 0; // if the texture has mip maps then set it to 0 in order to use them all.
t2d.ArraySize = 1;
t2d.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
t2d.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
t2d.BindFlags = BindFlags;
if(!t2d.MipLevels) // only set if the texture has mip maps.
    t2d.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA sd;
ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));

sd.pSysMem = m_DDSData;

switch (t2d.Format) {
case DXGI_FORMAT_BC1_UNORM:
    sd.SysMemPitch = 8 * (m_Header.dwWidth / 4);
    break;
case DXGI_FORMAT_BC2_UNORM:
case DXGI_FORMAT_BC3_UNORM:
    sd.SysMemPitch = 16 * (m_Header.dwWidth / 4);
    break;
case DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM:
case DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM:
    sd.SysMemPitch = m_Header.dwWidth * 4;
    break;
default:
    return Log("Unsupported texture format.");
}

hr = pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&t2d, &sd, &m_pTexture2D);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return Log("Failed to create texture.");
```

When my code runs and finds a texture with mip maps it ends up failling, and this is the  error message I get on debug:

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D: The format (0x4a, BC2_UNORM) cannot be bound as a RenderTarget, or cast to a format that could be bound as a RenderTarget. Therefore this format does not support D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #92: CREATETEXTURE2D_UNSUPPORTEDFORMAT]

But if it finds a texture with no mip maps, or even a texture with mip maps but I set the mip maps on the texture desciption to 1, I get no error message. As in the error message says, I'm not being able to bind the texture to the render target, but if I try to use `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS` I get an error message saying the texture needs to be bound to `D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't use the D3D11 runtime to generate mipmaps for compressed textures. You're expected to preprocess them using something like NVidia texture tools.

Comment: So in order to use mipmaps I have to use tools to create different layers of them, like multiple shader resources? I am actually feeling silly right now as I thought DirectX would do all the hard work for me :(

Comment: The spec for the compressed textures only defines how to convert the compressed bytes into colors. The method of getting from colored pixels to compressed bytes is not defined. As such the compression method is left up to the end user and is not implemented by the D3D11 runtime. It is also typically quite slow and not something you want to run at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic generation of mipmaps does not support Block Compressed formats. You can confirm this using `CheckFormatSupport`.

```
bool autogen = false;
UINT fmtSupport = 0;
hr = d3dDevice->CheckFormatSupport(format, &fmtSupport);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (fmtSupport & D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_MIP_AUTOGEN))
{
    // 10level9 feature levels do not support auto-gen mipgen for volume textures
    if ((resDim != D3D11_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE3D)
        || (d3dDevice->GetFeatureLevel() >= D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0))
    {
        autogen = true;
    }
}
```

Generally you are expected to compress your textures offline and generate mipmaps as part of that processing. These can be stored in DDS files and then loaded complete with mips at runtime.

See [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex) for a C++ library that supports mipmap generation, Block Compression, and a DDS codec. It includes the `DDSTextureLoader` module as well which is a light-weight DDS file loader.

> For very large data sets, there have been alternative schemes used where the high-resolution image is compressed using some lossy format (like JPEG) which is loaded at runtime, then a software or GPU-based box filter generates the mips. Then all levels of that texture are compressed using a [Fast Block Compression](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Resources#fast-block-compression-schemes) scheme. It doesn't have the same quality as offline compression, but for some scenarios it's worth the trade-off.

> Remember that Block Compression formats have a fixed 2:1 or 4:1 compression ratio, but the advantage is that you never have to decompress them as the hardware can use it directly to render.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, so you're saying that in order to use a compressed format with mip maps, the actual mips have to already be stored on the DDS file, and if the file have mip maps DirectX will use them? Or do I need to set something like the sampler state to actually use the mip maps?

Comment: If the DDS file contains mip levels, then [DDSTextureLoader](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DDSTextureLoader) will load them into the resource. As for rendering with them, it depends on what sampler state you are using but generally the 'default' is using ``D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR`` which does use mipmaps if present in the resource.